# How does the R-gmp package treat "Inf"?

Tags: r, gmp

I noticed the following when running `gmp` from `R` :

```
Rgames> log2(Inf)
[1] Inf
Rgames> log2(as.bigz(Inf))
[1] 8000
```

What's happening here?  Or does the `gmp` language (or `gmp::log2.bigz` method) just not support the concept of "Inf" ?

EDIT: Josh's comment is correct: it's not the `log2` function per se but rather the fact that `as.bigz` appears to convert `Inf` to `2^8000` as a `bigz` integer. Changed title to match.

BTW, there's also this:

```
Rgames> log2(-Inf)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
NaNs produced 
Rgames> log2(as.bigz(-Inf))
[1] NaN
```

EDIT: that was stupid. `log2(negative_anything)` is `NaN`

But,

```
Rgames> log2(-as.bigz(-Inf))
[1] 8000
```

Fits with Josh's answer.

Comment: The official GMP library doesn't support Inf/NaN (MPFR does though), so this is entirely up to the R wrapper (which I know nothing about).

Comment: Have a look at (the printed value of) `as.bigz(Inf)` to see that this has nothing to do with `log2`, which seems to behave quite reasonably...

Comment: Hi Carl -- so now that you know how the R package **gmp** treats `as.bigz(Inf)`, what's the question? Are you asking why that design decision was made? Whether it's a property of the underlying GMP library? Where/whether this is documented? Something else? (I do agree that the behavior is odd and unexpected...)

Comment: @Josh, I would like to know which piece of software made this decision -- based on @Marc Glisse 's comment I guess it's not the GMP library -- and if there was a reason for it.  You can imaging my original surprise when I deliberately tried to break things by doing `log2(as.bigz(2^7000))` (that feeds an `Inf` to `as.bigz`, of course)

Comment: If you download the sources for **gmp**, and search for "Inf" in `$gmp-HOME$/src/bigintegerR.cc`, you'll find the following lines: `/// New:   numeric '+- Inf'  give  +- "Large" instead of NA` and a bit later `else { // dj is +- Inf : use LARGE ( =   +- 2 ^ 80000 -- arbitrarily )`. My guess is that since the GMP library doesn't have a concept/representation of `Inf`, the R package authors had to make some decision about how to pass on user-supplied `Inf` values to the external library. It looks like they used to convert `Inf` to `NA`, and now they convert it to 2^80000`.

Comment: @Josh - thanks.  I'd started to search the tarball but hadn't got there.  Go ahead and post that as the answer; I'll ping the maintainer to request they put that conversion value into the help files.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- If you don't mind, I'll let you post and accept the answer, as I'll be busy for quite a while now. I think contacting the maintainer is a fine idea. Just grep'd the man directory, and the only current mention of `Inf` is an unrelated detail in `Stirling.Rd`.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting Josh's detective work for him, per request:

If you download the sources for `gmp`, and search for "Inf" in `$gmp-HOME$/src/bigintegerR.cc`, you'll find the following lines:

```
/// New: numeric '+- Inf' give +- "Large" instead of NA
```

and a bit later

```
else { // dj is +- Inf : use LARGE ( = +- 2 ^ 80000 -- arbitrarily )
```

My guess is that since the GMP library doesn't have a concept/representation of `Inf`, the R package authors had to make some decision about how to pass on user-supplied `Inf` values to the external library. It looks like they used to convert `Inf` to `NA`, and now they convert it to `2^80000`.